# How to fix error with pytorch conv2d function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to use conv2d function on these two tensors:

```
Z = np.random.choice([0,1],size=(100,100))
Z = torch.from_numpy(Z).type(torch.FloatTensor)

print(Z)

tensor([[0., 0., 1.,  ..., 1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 1., 1.],
        ...,
        [1., 0., 1.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 0., 1.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 0., 0.]
```

and

```
filters = torch.tensor(np.array([[1,1,1],
                        [1,0,1],
                        [1,1,1]]), dtype=torch.float32)

print(filters)

tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])
```

But when I try to do `torch.nn.functional.conv2d(Z,filters)` this error returns:

`RuntimeError: weight should have at least three dimensions`

I really don't understand what is the problem here. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to `torch.nn.functional.conv2d(input, weight)` should be

[image]

You can use `unsqueeze()` to add fake batch and channel dimensions thus having sizes: input: `(1, 1, 100, 100)` and weight: `(1, 1, 3, 3)`.

```
torch.nn.functional.conv2d(Z.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0), filters.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0))
```

Comment: thanks, but new tensors shape is ([1,1,98,98])

Comment: yes, that's expected, what shape do you want it to be? You can use `output.squeeze().squeeze()` to get 98x98.

Comment: well when i try to do ```(torch.nn.functional.conv2d(Z.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0), filters.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0))==3) & (Z==0)``` it says ```RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (98) must match the size of tensor b (100) at non-singleton dimension 3```, however to must work

Comment: it won't work because the output has size 98x98, and Z has size 100x100.

Comment: You'll have to add `padding=1` in `conv2d()` to get the output of 100x100.